# Como inserir um array de tamanho desconhecido dentro da base de dados?

Tags: php, mysql

Estou tentando inserir no banco de dados varias linhas com dados que vem de um array. Eu nunca tinha feito algo assim, pois sempre insiro uma linha de cada vez.
O que será que estou fazendo de errado?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Amigo, vejo que você está utilizando a extensão do MySQL `INSERT INTO 'table' SET ...`, para multiplos valores você precisa utilizar a notação padrão do SQL que é `INSERT INTO 'table' ('col1', 'col2', 'col3') VALUES ('row1val1', 'row1val2', 'row1val3'), ('row2val1', ...) ...`

Comment: Tiago, sugiro que nunca coloque seu código como imagem, a regra de formação é colocar em blocos de código, facilita o entendimento e que sua questão seja respondida. Da forma que está ela pode inclusive ser removida pela moderação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supondo que `$this->db` seja sua conexão MySQLi

```
public function addItemCaja($teste) {
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO item_juego (id_caja, id_item, cantidad) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");

    foreach($teste as $item){
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $item['id_caja']); //supondo que id_caja é integer
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $item['id_item']); //supondo que id_caja é integer
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $item['cantidad']); //supondo que id_caja é integer

        $stmt->execute();
    }

    $stmt->close();
}
```

Fazendo dessa forma você evita também problemas com SQL Injection.